# Simple_Form: Make two forms work with eachother (dropdown and search)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, sorting, simple-form

I have two forms, one containing a dropdown where the user can choose how a list is beeing sorted, the other one containing a searchfield, where the user can search through that list. Now if a user searches for "test" and ten results show up, I want the user to be able to choose from the dropdown, how the results are beeing sorted. Accordingly if he sorts the whole list, I want himto be able to search through the list, with the results showing up in the sorted way he choose before. Due to code restrictions I have to keep those two inputs in different forms.

Here is the sort-dropdown:

```
= simple_form_for path, :method => "get", html: {id: "sortform"} do |f|
  = f.input :sort, :collection => [t(:'videos.date'), t(:'videos.title'), t(:'videos.length')], :label => false, :required => false, :selected => params[:sort], input_html: {class: "control", :id => "sort_dropdown", :name => :sort}, :include_blank => t(:'videos.sort')
```

And here is the search:

```
= simple_form_for path, :method => 'get', :label => t(:'videos.search'), html: {id: "search-form"} do |f|
  = f.input :q, { input_html: { class: 'form-control searchbar', :name => :q, id: "search", :value => params[:q]}, :placeholder => t(:'videos.search'), :required => false, :label => false}
```

Is it possible to keep the two inputs seperate or would it be way easier to use just one form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use separate forms if you need to, just store the other parameter in a hidden field in each of the forms.

```
= simple_form_for path, :method => "get", html: {id: "sortform"} do |f|
  = f.input :sort, :collection => [t(:'videos.date'), t(:'videos.title'), t(:'videos.length')], :label => false, :required => false, :selected => params[:sort], input_html: {class: "control", :id => "sort_dropdown", :name => :sort}, :include_blank => t(:'videos.sort')
  = f.input :q, as: :hidden, input_html: { :name => :q, :value => params[:q] }

= simple_form_for path, :method => 'get', :label => t(:'videos.search'), html: {id: "search-form"} do |f|
  = f.input :q, { input_html: { class: 'form-control searchbar', :name => :q, id: "search", :value => params[:q]}, :placeholder => t(:'videos.search'), :required => false, :label => false}
  = f.input :sort, as: :hidden, collection: [t(:'videos.date'), t(:'videos.title'), t(:'videos.length')], :selected => params[:sort], input_html: {class: "control", :id => "sort_dropdown", :name => :sort}, :include_blank => t(:'videos.sort')
```